# Is it faster to hash a long string for comparisons or compare the two strings?

Tags: java, string, performance, hash

Let's say I have a list of very long strings (40-1000 characters). A user needs to be able to enter a term into the list and the list will report whether the term exists.

Barring storage, is it more efficient to store a hash alongside the long strings, and then when a user attempts a lookup it hashes the input and compares it to a list of hashes?

[There are similar answers here, but they aren't quite generalized enough.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658065/is-it-faster-to-search-for-a-large-string-in-a-db-by-its-hashcode)

Comment: Consider Lucene: http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the data fits in the heap (i.e., in memory), your best bet is to use a Set (or Map if there is data associated with each string). Either change your storage from a List to a Set (using HashSet) or maintain a separate Set if you also really need a List.

The time to compute the `hashcode()` of a string is proportional to the length of the string. The time to look for the string is constant with respect to the number of strings in the collection (once the hashcode has been computed), assuming a properly-implemented `hashcode()` and properly-sized Set.

If instead you use `equals()` on an unsorted list, your lookup time will probably be proportional to the number of items in the list. If you keep the list sorted, you could do binary search with the number of comparisons to lookup one string proportional to the log of the number of items in the list (and each comparison will have to compare characters until a difference is found).

In essence, the Set is sort of like keeping the hashcode of the strings handy, but it goes one step further and stores the data in such a way that it is very quick to jump straight to the elements of the collection that have that hashcode value.

Note that an equals comparison of two strings can bail out as soon as a difference is found, but might have to compare every character in the two strings (when they are equal). If your strings have similar, long prefixes it can hurt performance. Sometimes, you can benefit (performance-wise) from knowledge of the content of your data types. For example, if all your strings begin with the same 1K prefix and only differ in the end, you could benefit from overriding the `equals()` implementation to compare from the end to the start, so you find differences earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough.

First, I assume you mean "I have a *set* of very long strings", because *list* is very inefficient structure for presence lookups

Some ideas:

- Depends on the properties of your strings' set (i. e. the domain), prefix tree could appear to be dramatically more efficient by memory and speed, than any sort of hash table. Prefix tree means comparisons, not hash computation.
- Otherwise, you should end up using some sort of hash table, which means you should compute hash code anyway, at least once for each string. In this case, it seems reasonable to store hash codes along with the strings. But for strict correctness, in the end you should probably compare strings by contents anyway, because hash collisions are possible.
- Theoretically, max speed of well-distributed hash functions is 3-4 bytes / clock cycle (i. e. hash function consumes 3-4 bytes per CPU cycle).
- Speed of stream comparison - depends on some conditions and how your code is compiled, there are instuctions on modern CPUs that allow to compare up to 16 bytes per cycle. Interesting, that `Arrays.equals` methods are intrinsified, but there is no "raw" memory comparison method in `sun.misc.Unsafe` class.